# Why is conditional type needed when using mapped type on tuple?

Tags: typescript, generics, types, conditional-types, mapped-types

This works:

```
class Dog {
    speak() {
        return "woof" as const;
    }
}

type ExtractSpeak<T extends [...Dog[]]> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Dog ? ReturnType<T[P]["speak"]> : never };

// Type of Example is ["woof", "woof"]
type Example = ExtractSpeak<[Dog, Dog]>;
```

But, why doesn't it work without the conditional type?

```
// Error: Type '"speak"' cannot be used to index type 'T[P]'. (2536)
type ExtractSpeak<T extends [...Dog[]]> = { [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]["speak"]> };
```

When would `T[P]` refer to anything other than a type having a `speak` method which returns `"woof"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#27995](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27995).  When you make a [mapped type over a tuple/array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) the type that comes out will also be a tuple/array; that is, you're only really mapping over the numeric indices of the array.  But inside the definition of the mapped type, the compiler doesn't pay attention to this.  Instead, it sees `K in keyof T` (where `T` is an array type) as possibly iterating `K` over *every possible key*, like this:

```
type DogArrayKeys = keyof [Dog, Dog];
// number | "0" | "1" | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "pop" | 
// "push" | "concat" | "join" | "reverse" | "shift" | "slice" | "sort" | 
// "splice" | "unshift" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | 
// ... 14 more ... | "includes"
```

And since, for example, `[Dog, Dog]["length"]` is of type `2` and not `Dog`, the compiler won't let you treat `T[K]` as `Dog`.  Blecch.

Anyway, it's a bug and it would be nice if it were fixed.  I suppose you can go to ms/TS#27995 and give it a .  But realistically it is probably not high on any priority list (it's on the backlog for now).  The standard workaround is just to use a conditional type like `Extract<T[K], Dog>` and move on, which is basically what you have above.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAiD2BzaBvAUNT0IAcCmYA1gBQCUqGWVATngC4Cu1AdtAEQDu88AZm9JGjB4zCHQDclTAF80stHQCe+aAFEAHnWphgdAMr4iAHgAq0PJrzMAJjADaAOicJEdgLpuAfNAC8FKnYACtAAlqyEeIq80CZuAFzQAEr0TMwmynhGGlo6dKZBbgA0cEiedmy4BIRsXtDSkmgA9I0xGdDRGmAAtjggeKH2nNx8xUO8NQptnT19vmqa2roGVUZ2LsUuXg2TKi4AgtTaigDSkTB+EVE80GtIG0huks3QzAxdAEZ41NAAPuwADPw-mwAIxA9h9ZiIOgAC3BbDo8D0WjCiHhiIAMvBgGA+sjqKj4Th4DgiQwIHDfuxhMwcXQgU0WmwAFbwMLw2gANy+EDw8IpIR49KpFRAIWAfJFEHg1GFwNwYol8IYohhgrl7DC1gsAHk+CLwGIAJI2XX6v6M6BOBzQEEAFmgXRl-WtIrCoAY2ogbCAA)

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thank you so much!